# Tornado behind Nginx for websockets - timeout

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket, tornado

We are running our server in AWS EC2 M4.xlarge instance and we are seeing unexplained behavior with the websocket connections.
***Problem:*** Our clients (running python websocket-client to connect) that are connected to the tornado websocket server behind nginx, are **ALL** being dropped at the same time and for the same reason of ping/pong timedout after some time (between 3-6hrs) of being connected. Not sure if we are setting some configuration incorrectly.

Here is the configuration for our sysctl.conf:

`net.core.somaxconn = 65536
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15`

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 65000;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;   
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is our configuration for the application server.

```
upstream ourserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:9999;
}
server {
    listen  80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name **DNS**;
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols    SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers    HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my.key;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    keepalive_timeout 15s;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    location /secure/ {
        proxy_pass http://ourserver;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://ourserver;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My `on_message` had a blocking call which takes between 20ms to 200ms due to DB call. This delay propagates to the remaining events coming in, which eventually led to sockets being dropped by clients.